# Filter a queryset in Django based on a changing value

Tags: django

I build a Blogpost App with Django and want comments under the blogpost. I can already post new comments, and see comments, but I see every comment under every blogpost. .

```
class blogpost(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class blogcommment(models.Model):
    user   = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    post = models.ForeignKey(blogpost, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

def blogpost_detail_view (request, slug):
    # Blogeintrag anzeigen
    obj = blogpost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = blogcommentform(request.POST or None)
    qs = blogcommment.objects.filter(***What should stay here and why?***)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = blogcommment.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
        form = blogcommentform
    template_name = 'blogpost_detail.html'
    context = {"object": obj,'form': form,'object_list': qs}
    return render(request, template_name, context)

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ object.content }}</p>
<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type='submit'>Senden</button>
</form>
{% for object in object_list %}
       {{ object.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

class blogcommentform(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: I was wrong: Every comment is linked to the first blogpost :/

Comment: Show the code how you save comment

Comment: okay I added the code

Comment: Where is comment saving code? You include html

Comment: i added the form. sry i am so new i dont know what part does what

Comment: You have something like `blogpost_detail_view `

Comment: This is all the relatet code I think. I added the form at the end. I really do not know what could I add, sry for my incompetence. I save the comment inside blogpost_detail_view

Comment: That means you need to add a view to save the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this

```
qs = blogcommment.objects.filter(post_id=obj.id)
```

In `blogcommment` model you have a reference to `blogpost`. So, you can easily filter comment for which blog post related to it.

Comment: Thanks it works. But my comments are not relatet to the right blogpost in the database. How could I fix this? :)

Comment: Show me your code, how you save the blogcomment. It all time linked to 1st post because of this `post = models.ForeignKey(blogpost, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)` here you set `default=1` as a result if you failed to save correct post reference it's set `1` by default.

Comment: how do you mean result? it adds all things in the database, but I dont know how link the right blogpost. you are right it only uses the default./

Comment: `print(form.cleaned_data)`

Answer (score 0):

```
qs = blogcommment.objects.filter(post=obj)
```

This will tell the queryset to filter all blogcomments that have the current specific blogpost as their `post` reference.